# How to install Windows Media Player?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I need windows media player for  a windows app.  However they require a windows verification ID for downloading for their web site.  I can't get the current installation package.  Is there another location that I can download it from?  I am using the most up to date wine which in it's wine tricks it doesn't have WMP9 in it.

Comment: Why do you even need WMP? Everything can be done better natively.

Comment: One app. in order to run in WINE requires it and I can't get a translation.  I need the app.  It is called overdrive media console.  I might be able to live without it, but what a life that would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with a lot of other people that you can play a lot of formats without Windows Media Player but if you still want it, you can always try downloading [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/)

This application isn't just for games but also for media, internet and many other applications that run on Windows that you would like to use on Linux. When you want to download it, go [here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html), select Ubuntu and follow the instructions on how to place the repo onto your computer. The installation of PlayOnLinux did take some time so be sure you can leave your computer on for a long period of time.

Once the installation is complete, you will be be able to see PlayOnLinux in the "Games" category. When you execute the application, you will be asked some additional questions to complete the setup of PlayOnLinux. Once complete, you will be able to add Windows Media Player from the INSTALL button. I attached a screenshot to this post to see what the final result should be.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I don't actually play music on it.  It is just required for some windows emulation.

Answer (score 1):

**BUG WORKAROUND**

To disable the annoying box which shows you how to enable the mini-player mode, just add this key on Windows Register:

open `Winetricks`

```
"Select the default wine prefix""
"Run regedit"
```

go to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MediaPlayer\Preferences
```

and add this DWORD value

```
"ShowMinimizeDialog" | (value = 0)
```

Comment: Please ask your question in a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).  Thanks!